# Get Product Unique ID inside onClick(View v)

Tags: android

I want to pass unique ID of the product in the ProductListAdapter so that when I click the listview Item, I get its unique id on the onclickListener.

```
public class ProductListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product>{

    private List<Product> products;

    public ProductListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Product> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        products = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).
                    inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        Product product = products.get(position);

        TextView nameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
        nameText.setText(product.getName());

        nameText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //I want to get the unique ID here.
                //I want to call products.getUID() here

            }
        });

        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        String price = formatter.format(product.getPrice());
        TextView priceText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.priceText);
        priceText.setText(price);

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

In the code above I am passing Product Name & Price. Both are part of view. So no problem with that.

To get product unique_ID

```
products.getUID()
```

But my unique_id in the model is not part of the view. I want the unique_id to be accessible in the onclickListener. However, the onclickListener only has view as pram.

```
setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    //I want to get the unique ID here.
    //I want to call products.getUID() here

    }
});
```

So what is the solution here

Comment: call this inside click products.get(position).getUID();

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ListView` then you can do as below

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    productlist.get(position).getUID();
  }
});
```